# Горизонтальная полоска со стрелкой средствами CSS

Tags: css

Всем привет, возможно сделать такую картинку:

[image: Линия, изогнутая посередине в виде стрелки вниз]

средствами CSS, которая отображалась бы так же даже при изменении ширины?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2N68/ получилось как-то так

Comment: @soledar10, в Вашем варианте у блока нет границы снизу, как показано на картинке. Для того чтобы она была, нужно создать два треугольника снизу, один цвета фона, другой цвета границы, и наложить один на другой. Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/8aYgG/

Comment: Спасибо Павел Азанов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ab4Se/

```css
body {
    background: #fff;
}
.block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.block::after, .block::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #f00;
    /* Добавляем тень для уголка */
    z-index: -1;
    /* Прячем за основным блоком */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* Поворачиваем на 45º */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.block::before {
    z-index: 1;
    /* Накладываем поверх, чтобы скрыть следы тени */
    box-shadow: none;
    /* Прячем тень */
}
.block1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
.block1::after, .block1::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #00f;
    /* Добавляем тень для уголка */
    z-index: -1;
    /* Прячем за основным блоком */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* Поворачиваем на 45º */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.block1::before {
    z-index: 1;
    /* Накладываем поверх, чтобы скрыть следы тени */
    box-shadow: none;
    /* Прячем тень */
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
```

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо! Можете еще ответить на вопрос? Понятно, что делает тень, а почему не сработало свойство color? И как происходит центрирование, при измении ширины блока, за счёт отрицательного маржина?

Comment: центрирование за счет left: 50%; минус половина ширины угла в данном случае 10px margin-left: -10px;

Comment: background: #fff - это белый цвет